# Is there a way to know the color (white, black, rose gold, etc) of an iOS device in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'd like to know the color of my user's device. This way I can show some images of their actual phone. I don't want to show a black iPhone 6 if the user is using a white iPhone 6.

Is this possible with Swift?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate is old but nothing has changed.